# Scala how many futures can I create

Tags: scala, future, reactive-programming

```
val iter = (1 to 1000).iterator.map { i =>
  accountService.getAccountDataSyncList(i, 200)
}.takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).flatten.map(acc => produceReport(acc.bindAccount))
Future.sequence(iter.toList)
```

I iterate over 1 to 1000 pages of accounts and create at most 200 * 1000 futures,

Will this  use a lot of memory ?

Is this `create all task as future then forget` pattern performance friendly ?

Comment: That depends on many things which are not mentioned in your question. Maybe it's possible to optimize your algorithm, so that you don't create tens or hundreds of thousands of futures. It also depends on how "heavy" the work is. After all, why not trying it out?

Comment: It seems you might be under the impression that each `Future` is or has a thread. That is most certainly not the case. The fixed space overhead of an instance of `Future` (which is actually a trait, so there can be multiple implementations) is modest. Creating 200,000 of them would be no problem on most systems (certainly any desktop or server–mobile or embedded is another story).

Comment: @RandallSchulz Thanks, I am using a 512MB heap java virtual machine. So I decide to not refactor this piece of code util my vm oom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much memory it will take depends on how much memory of your each callback costs and how many threads you specified to execute the futures.

Comment: I think all futures are created before they all begin to execute.

Comment: @jilen from the java objects point of view you're right, they're all created before each will be started

Comment: A future object itslef usually doesn't take up too much memory, except you have too many objects, while it will really take up memory when its method runs. GC is always a big ememy of Java though.

Comment: @Light I tried it , and gc is not the enemy here. But I post too much task, the cpu is now a busy man, load goes to `10+`